# Error while creating ip header for a customized packet

Tags: c, sockets, packets

I am going through a piece of code for packet injector. When I tried to compile it, It is showing the error :

```
IP-Packet-Injection.c:155: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
IP-Packet-Injection.c:156: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Code for that particular part is :

```
unsigned char *CreateIPHeader(/* Customize this as an exercise */)
{
        struct iphdr *ip_header;

        ip_header = (struct iphdr *)malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr));

        ip_header->version = 4;
        ip_header->ihl = (sizeof(struct iphdr))/4 ;
        ip_header->tos = 0;
        ip_header->tot_len = htons(sizeof(struct iphdr));
        ip_header->id = htons(111);
        ip_header->frag_off = 0;
        ip_header->ttl = 111;
        ip_header->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        ip_header->check = 0; /* We will calculate the checksum later */
      /*this is line 155 */ (in_addr_t)ip_header->saddr = inet_addr(SRC_IP);
      /*this is line 156 */ (in_addr_t)ip_header->daddr = inet_addr(DST_IP);


        /* Calculate the IP checksum now : 
           The IP Checksum is only over the IP header */

        ip_header->check = ComputeIpChecksum((unsigned char *)ip_header, ip_header->ihl*4);

        return ((unsigned char *)ip_header);

}
```

I have shown line 155 and 156 in the code. I can't see any problem there. Can anybody tell me what the error can be? Thanks in advance.
Operating system : Ubuntu,  compiler : GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a cast is an rvalue, so you can't assign to it. For a situation like this, you typically have to do something like:

```
*(in_addr_t *)(&(ip_header->saddr)) = in_addr(SRC_IP);
```

I.e., take the address, cast that to a pointer to the correct type, and dereference that pointer. Just make sure the defined type of the `saddr` and `daddr` members is something that *can* actually hold the address. It normally should be, but it won't hurt to double check.